# Clipboard > Type Clipboard Text doesn't work on Server 2022 Guests for Powershell window

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-2022

I can paste text into the guest OS using the Clipboard > "Type Clipboard Text" menu command, *except* when I am trying to paste into a PowerShell window on a Server 2022 guest.
If I launch cmd or notepad, I can paste, but if it is a PowerShell window, then nothing gets typed to the screen.
Is there some setting in PowerShell that I am missing that disables this kind of typing? I have only noticed this in Server 2022

Comment: What is this guest? A virtual machine? A remote control session? An RDP session? How about some details?

Comment: You may want to report that to Microsoft. As a workaround, use an Enhanced Session.

Comment: The guest is a virtual machine. I am connecting to it through hyper-v manager by finding it in the list of virtual machines, right-clicking, and selecting "connect.." the "Clipboard > Type Clipboard text" is a menu option when connecting to virtual machines in this way.

Comment: I have submitted the problem to Microsoft using the feedback hub.